# physics-motion in straight line body dropped

Tags: physics, motion

A tennis ball is dropped on to the floor from a height of `4m.it` rebounds to a height of `3m.if` the ball was in contact with floor for 0.010 sec, what was its average acceleration during contact.
**`acceleration=[(2gh)^1/2]+[(2gh)^1/2]/t=[(2*9.8*3)^1/2]+[(2*9.8*4)^1/2]/0.01=1652m/s`**

i have doubt in while using time.in the expression for acceleration "t" is the time required to travel the distance.so in that case
acceleration will be=[velocity of fall+velocity of rebound/time required for falling+rebounding]

but here we used `"time in ball in contact with the floor"` instead of total time. what is concept/logic behind it.

Please guide me the correct way to achieve my objective.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 0):

For the falling ball V^2 = 2*g*h so V at first contact with ground is sqrt(78.4) = 8.85 m/s downwards.
For the rising ball, the same argument can be used to show V = 7.67 m/s upwards.
So deltaV is 8.85+7.67 = 16.52 m/s.

But deltaV = a*t so a = deltaV/t = 16.52/0.01 = 1652 m/s (equal to ~168.6 times gravitational acceleration).

I would suggest that if you want to understand this a little better, you should begin by searching for a tutorial explaining **kinematics**.